# How to add UIView in UIWebview, a feature like UITextView exclusionPaths

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiwebview, uitextview

Hello I want to add UIView in UIWebView, like there is is a HTML, that is to be loaded in UIWebView, in between this HTML I want to add a UIView, somewhat magazine like structure.
I know this is possible with UITextView exclusionPaths,but I want to achieve this with UIWebView.
Can anybody know how to do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Suggestion : UIWebView is deprecated so use WKWebView

Comment: It is unlikely there is an out-of-the-box solution to this. You need to constrain the requirements of your question for people to be able to help. How about a sketch showing where this view is to be located on top of the browser? 
Further, will you be allowing the user to load _any_ website inside this web view, or only a website that you have control over to design?
Fundamentally, you probably should reevaluate your requirements to ensure there is not a better approach to solve this problem.